# How to exclude the path of the file of the SaveFileDialog box in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am building a Notepad demo application in Winform using C#.
When I click the Save or SaveAs button, I want to change the Title of the Form to the File Name excluding the path of the file name.

#### (e.g   "Demo.txt", but not "D:\Demo.txt")

```
private string fileName;
private void mnuSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            sw.Write(txtMain.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }

        this.Text = dlg.FileName;                             
    }
```

In the above code, `dlg.FileName` returns the full path of the file name.
In the OpenFileDialog, there is `dlg.SafeFileName` which only returns the file name.  But SaveFileDialog does not have that property.
How can I get only the file name in SaveFileDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Path.GetFileName()` Method from `System.IO`:

```
Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName);
```